# Is there any rule against fake bounties?

Tags: discussion

Are there any official rules against putting fake bounties at the end of your posts?

The links work in both of them, but you can not select the text.

This one looks quite convincing on the main site.

> [image: This question has an open][image: bounty][image: worth][image: 2,700][image: reputation from][image: X-27][image: ending in 7 days]
>   [image: this question has not received enough attention.]

This one looks *very* convincing everywhere.

[image: This question has an open][image: bounty][image: worth 2,700 reputation from][image: X-27][image: ending in 7 days]

Would things such as this simply be considered spam?

Comment: Tags go above the bounty, so this is easy to detect. Another tell-tale hint is that it would not be featured as a question with a bounty.

Answer (score 6):

## No. This should not be allowed

The big issue is this "joke" is extra noise in your post (like a greeting/signature). SE doesn't permit such things. As [@NoviceInDisguise](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6204/noviceindisguise) observed,  it will be edited out quickly, and you will only succeed in annoying a user who has to go to all the trouble.

Furthermore, you may have to deal with and upset user expecting a bounty. Probably best just to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

The ease with which you can simulate a bounty moderately well is amazing, however it is easy to detect if it is real or not. (Tags go above the bounty, so this is easy to detect. Another tell-tale hint is that it would not be featured as a question with a bounty, etc) 
Personally I think they will get edited out very quickly as our community is great at reviewing questions.

However repeatedly posting posts like this could result in serious actions on the part of our moderators, and could result in your suspension from the site.

> This answer has an open [bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) worth [image: rep] reputation from [GiantCowFilms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) ending **in 5 days**.
>
> `This answer should be accepted.`

Comment: your link to giant cow's profile also goes to the bounty page, and the +2,700 is not at the same line height as the other text.

Comment: I know, I literally typed this using only one image in about 20 seconds.